# MySQL Ordering from another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

I have been looking for a solution for this for over an hour now and decided to resort to asking here.

I am creating a "Twitter-like", following system for users of my Website and I wanted to be able to display each and every one of the users that a specific user follows or is followed by, I also want to then order this by the timestamp on the follow table, descending so that the latest follower is at the top.

The solutions I have come across seem to use inner joins etc. which is all well and good, but I was wondering whether there is a logical solution for my current query to do this.

Table structures:
users:

```
id | username
```

follows:

```
id | follower_id | following_id | timestamp
```

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT follower_id FROM follows WHERE following_id = $user_id) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Of course this will simply order by the user ID, how would I (using the current query structure), be able to add the order to list by the follows timestamp?

Comment: The logical solution IS to use a join. What is your issue with that?

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

```
"SELECT users.* FROM users 
INNER JOIN follows ON follows.follower_id = users.id 
WHERE follows.following_id = $user_id 
ORDER BY follows.timestamp DESC";
```

Comment: This does not fully answer the question; he wants to sort by user id ASC then timestamp DESC; also, add an explanation rather than a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using multiple columns like this:

```
ORDER BY [column1] [ASC|DESC], [columm2] [ASC|DESC], ...
```

Therefore, edit your query's order by clause to include the second column and sort it descending.

You **must** use a join to add the column; here's the basic syntax of a join:

```
SELECT [table_name].[column_name], ...
FROM [table1]
JOIN [table2] ON [join condition]
...
```

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
JOIN follows ON users.id = follows.following_id
WHERE follows.following_id = $user_id
ORDER BY users.id ASC, follows.timestamp DESC
```

As far as I know, there is **no** way to do this without joining the tables; perhaps its possible to sort the returned list, but no guarantees):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT follower_id FROM follows
  WHERE following_id = $user_id
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

The above may or may not work (I didn't test it); if it does **not**, you ***must*** use a **join query**.

Comment: you can't order by a column that is not in the resultset

Comment: Oh, well he should use a join; sorry, I skimmed